# Django generates too many SQL queries for models.ForeignKey

Tags: python, django

A *Model* class has a foreign key (*models.ForeignKey*) referring to another *Model* class.

Django generates too many SQL queries for this foreign key. When a *admin.StackedInline* class uses the *Model* class, it tries to make a select list containing all items in the referred-to table (*ProductTemplate* in sample code below).

Is there a way to limit the foreign key to only list one item, instead of all items in the referred-to table?

Any other suggestions will also be highly appreciated. Let me know if you need more details.

```
In file admin.py:
...
class TransactionAttributeInlineAttribute(admin.StackedInline):
    model = models.TransactionAttribute
    verbose_name = 'Transaction Link'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Product Links'
class MyAttributeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [TransactionAttributeInlineAttribute]
    list_display = ['name','datatype','required']
...


In file models.py:
...
class TransactionAttribute(models.Model):
    product_template = models.ForeignKey(ProductTemplate)
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For foriegn key, Django by default generates a drop-down select widget with all items in the referred table, not only the linked item, but also all the others unrelated.

In my case, this behavior generated too many SQL queries that overwhelmed database. The fix is to get rid of the drop-down select, and restrict Django to show only the linked one item for the foreign key.

raw_id_fields = ['product_template']

See more discussions on the link below:
https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/models-foreignkey-caused-too-many-sql-queries/1649/5?u=simpleopen

**Code change for fix:**

```
class TransactionAttributeInlineAttribute(admin.StackedInline):
    model = models.TransactionAttribute
    raw_id_fields = ['product_template']
    verbose_name = 'Transaction Link'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Product Links'
```